# Improve performance for query to delete duplicates

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

My hosting company recently gave me this entry from the slow-query log. The rows examined seem excessive and might be helping to slow down the server. A test in phpMyAdmin resulted in duration of 0.9468 seconds.

The Check_in table ordinarily contains 10,000 to 17,000 rows. It also has one index: Num, unique = yes, cardinality = 10852, collation = A.

I would like to improve this query. The first five conditions following WHERE contain the fields to check to throw out duplicates.

```
# User@Host: fxxxxx_member[fxxxxx_member] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 5  Lock_time: 0  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 701321
use fxxxxx_flifo;
SET timestamp=1364277847;
DELETE FROM Check_in USING Check_in, 
Check_in as vtable WHERE 
    ( Check_in.empNum = vtable.empNum ) 
AND ( Check_in.depCity = vtable.depCity ) 
AND ( Check_in.travelerName = vtable.travelerName ) 
AND ( Check_in.depTime = vtable.depTime ) 
AND ( Check_in.fltNum = vtable.fltNum ) 
AND ( Check_in.Num > vtable.Num ) 
AND ( Check_in.accomp = 'NO' ) 
AND Check_in.depTime >= TIMESTAMPADD ( MINUTE, 3, NOW() )
AND Check_in.depTime < TIMESTAMPADD ( HOUR, 26, NOW() );
```

Edit:

- empNum int (6)
- lastName varchar (30)
- travelerName varchar (40)    (99.9% = 'All')
- depTime datetime
- fltNum varchar (6)
- depCity varchar (4)
- 23 fields total (including one blob, holding 25K images)

Edit:

```
ADD INDEX deleteQuery (empNum, lastName, travelerName, depTime, fltNum, depCity, Num)
```

Is this a matter of creating an index? If so, what type and what fields?

The last 3 conditions limit the number of rows, by asking if accomplished and within time period. Could they be better positioned (earlier) in the query? Is the 5th `AND ...` necessary?

Open to all ideas. Thanks for looking.

Comment: I sugest you check the execution plan: `explain select ...` (instead of delete). There you can check the fields you may need to index.

Comment: @Barranka Could you please explain that more. I don't yet understand indexes. Are you suggesting, `explain select * from Check_in` or `explain Num, empNum, depCity ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is to delete dupicates, the  the solution is to avoid having duplicates in the first place - define a unique index across the fields that you deeem to collectively define a duplicate (but you won't be able to create the index while you have duplicates in the database).

The index you need for *this* query is on (deptime,empnum,depcity,travellername,fltnum,num,accomp} *in that order*. The deptime field has to come first for it to optimize the 2 accesses on the table. Once you've removed the duplicates, make the index unique.

Leaving that aside for now, you've got a whole load of performance problems.

1) you appear to be offering some sort of commercial service - so why are you waiting for your ISP to tell you that your site is running like a dog?

2) while your indexes should be designed to prevent duplicates, there are many cases where other indexes will help with performance - but in order to understand what those are you needto look at all the queries running against your data.

3) the blob should probably be in a separate table

> Could they be better positioned (earlier) in the query?

Order of predicates at the same level in the query hierarchy has no impact on performance.

> is the 5th AND necessary?

If you mean 'AND ( Check_in.Num > vtable.Num )', then yes - without that it will remove *all* the rows that are duplicated - i.e. it won't leave one row behid.

Comment: Excellent suggestion in the second paragraph and about the blob. Not everybody starts programing with all the knowledge. There is much to learn. Hey, I even appreciated the 3rd paragraph. Issues are addressed one-by-one.

Comment: Your proposed index appears to have dropped the query time from 0.02 to 0.002.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly how to help without seeing the table definition.

Don't delete the self-join (the same table mentioned twice) because this query is clearing out duplicates (`check_in.Num > vtable.Num`).

Do you have an index on depTime?  If not, add one.

You may also want to add a compound index on

```
 (empNum,depCity,travelerName,depTime,fltNum)
```

to optimize the self-join.  You probably have to muck about a bit to figure out what works.

Comment: After adding an `index` on the 5 plus Num, the query really speeds up. Now running at 0.0228, for instance. That may have been the 'simple' trick. I will be read reading -> [How MySQL uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: 'muck about' sounds like highly technical advice.  :)

Comment: A single index on deptime,empNum,depCity,travelerName,fltNum (NB deptime first) would perform the function of the 2 indexes proposed by Ollie with a reduced overhead for inserts/updates/deletes.

Comment: BTW: mucking about is a well established practice for optimizing systems. But when you're paying someone to do it they describe it using terms like 'incremental path optimization', 'goal searching' and 'local minima avoidance'

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of indexes is to speed up searches and filters... the index is (in layman terms) a sorted table that pin-points each row of the data (which may be itself unsorted).

So, if you want to speed your delete query, it would help to know where the data is. So, as a set of thumb rules, you will need to add indexes to the following fields:

1. Every primary or foreign key
2. Every date on which you perform frequent searches / filters
3. Every numeric field on which you perform frequent searches / filters

I avoid indexes on text fields, since they are quite expensive (in terms of space), but if you need to perform frequent searches on text fields, you should also index them.

Comment: Please see edit for data types & added index. Is a correct answer to add an index on 7 items (6 bullets & Num (already unique)?? To your comment about text fields, are my varchars small enough? What would you suggest for index(es)?